# Google Classroom Error 400 InactiveCourseOwner

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

I am attempting to add a teacher to a course. I am assigning the teacher as the owner of the course. This is new course and this teacher is active in Google Admin but I am still getting this error. What should be my next steps?

**After speaking with Google Support, they found that the user (teacher) was deleted and recreated with the same email the next day. The classrooms were attached to the old instance of the email. This is what was causing the 400 InactiveCourseOwner error.**

Comment: Based from what I have read in the [Request Errors Page](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Request.Errors), the only way that an Error 400: InteractiveCourseOwner is encountered is when `...the course owner's account is deleted. The admin of the course owner needs to restore the course owner's account before taking the requested action...`.

Comment: By any chance, are you using a mobile application in accessing the classroom? If so, have you tried updating/reinstalling the mobile app?

Comment: @PatrickdC I think my issue may lie in that I can't find the class I am attempting to make in the existing classroom cache, it is in-fact there with a different inactive owner

Comment: Please take note that at this point, your issue is still not reproducible. Kindly add more details to your posted question so that we may have more ideas as to how to help you tackle your current issue. At this point, the only thing I can suggest is to try and activate the inactive course owner before trying to transfer the ownership of the course to the desired user.

Comment: @PatrickdC I have edited the issue to include what the issue was.